# How to correctly loop querySelectorAll for hyperlink translation (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, web, queryselectall

**Hello!**

Am working on an author's hyperlink translation in several languages.

Could someone help me correctly loop querySelectAll which translates some text for all elements collected by it, because it only translates the first hyperlink and not them all.

```
switch (pLang) {
    
    case "lv":        
        document.querySelectorAll('[title="John Davis publikācijas"]').innerHTML = "Džons Deivis";
    break;
    
    case "ru":        
        document.querySelectorAll('[title="Записи John Davis"]').innerHTML = "Джон Дэйвис";
    break;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll, it retursn list of elements you need to use loop, like foreach or for

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `forEach` to modify all the elements instead of just the first one:

```
switch (pLang)
{
    case "lv":        
        [... document.querySelectorAll('[title="John Davis publikācijas"]')].forEach((element)=>
        {
            element.innerHTML = "Džons Deivis";
        });
    break;
    
    case "ru":        
        [... document.querySelectorAll('[title="Записи John Davis"]')].forEach((element)=>
        {
            element.innerHTML = "Джон Дэйвис";
        });
    break;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for spreading into a new array. `forEach` is a supported method on a node list.

Comment: I always convert nodeList to arrays. I forget why. @trincot